# MySQL crashes after restoring from backup

Tags: mysql

I've restored my vserver from a backup which was created by my host.
After that my MySQL server is not starting anymore.

I've tried several ways to recovery my tables, but it's still not working.

This is what the error.log says:

```
140925 13:06:29 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140925 13:06:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140925 13:06:29 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': signed value 2097152 adjusted to     5242880
140925 13:06:29 [Warning] option 'innodb-additional-mem-pool-size': signed value 512000 adjusted to 524288
140925 13:06:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140925 13:06:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140925 13:06:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140925 13:06:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 5.0M
140925 13:06:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140925 13:06:29 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140925 13:06:29  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140925 13:06:29  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: Error: tablespace size stored in header is 3200 pages, but
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: the sum of data file sizes is only 2816 pages
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: Cannot start InnoDB. The tail of the system tablespace is
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: missing. Have you edited innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf in an
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: inappropriate way, removing ibdata files from there?
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: You can set innodb_force_recovery=1 in my.cnf to force
140925 13:06:30 InnoDB: a startup if you are trying to recover a badly corrupt database.
140925 13:06:30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140925 13:06:30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140925 13:06:30 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140925 13:06:30 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It's a Ubuntu 12.04 server with `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2`

This is my log when I try innodb_force_recovery=1: http://pastebin.com/FmNgcBJy

Comment: Have you tried the possible solutions in the messages?

Comment: Yes I've added innodb_force_recovery=1 in my my.cnf but it's still crashing.
Here's the log with that option:  http://pastebin.com/FmNgcBJy

Comment: How did you restore the database?

Comment: My server is hosted at Strato (German hoster). It offers a feature called "Backup control" which creates a backup every day in the morning up to 10 backups. I've used its restore feature and the server was shut down and completely overwritten with the backup.
EDIT: I need to use today's backup because of data that came over night. So it's not an option to use yesterday's backup.

Comment: Ask your host whether they freeze the virtual machine during the backup. Probably not. They created an inconsistent copy and your snapshot is unusable (in a state very similar to a corrupted hard disk following a power loss). You might be able to partially recover your data by [fiddling with the `innodb_force_recoovery`  option](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66833/18155), but do not hope for miracles.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to fix this problem?